# Curl Get Swift Storage files saved by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, curl, openstack-swift, object-storage

As it known Apache spark saves files by parts i.e `foo.csv/part-r-00000..`
I save files on Swift Object storage now I want want to get the files using Openstack swift API but when I do curl on `foo.csv` I get zero file

How I download the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can take any REST client and list content of the object store. Don't do curl on 'foo.txt', since it's zero size object. You need to list container with prefix 'foo.txt', this will return you all the parts. 
Alternatively you can use Apache Spark and read foo.txt (Spark will automatically list and return all the parts)

Comment: I know that I can list container for files but how can i list it using prefix?